# Multiple LUIS built-in entities in the same utterance

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am trying to understand how multiple instances of LUIS built-in entities would work, because LUIS does not allow tagging of built-in entities. For example, if have an utterance "Patient Jane Doe was born on 10th of May, 1956 and was injured in an accident on 19th of May, 1978". In this case, ideally, I would have liked to tag 2 datetime entities: patient date of birth and patient date of injury. But when LUIS passes these entities, this information is lost. Is there a way to disambiguate as to which date is which.

In the screenshot below, for utterance "patient date of birth is 10/10/1987 and date of injury is 1/1/2016", I received 2 entities from LUIS result, but how can I tell which one is date of injury and which one is date of birth. I cannot send these entities to my FormFlow form. **It looks like a major design flaw in how built-in entities work in LUIS because we cannot attach training labels to built-in entities.**

[image]

Comment: Have you already trained your model? If you've done so, then the next time you visit your intents LUIS should have gone in and labeled both of those dates.

Comment: I have elaborated my question...there is no way to get entity type labels for built-in entities

Comment: Did you find a way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding this, some of the built-in entities are not ML-built by LUIS, but rather provided by other MS teams, so customizing/labeling them is not an option.

That said, for some of the other built-ins, their recognizers are open source and can be found under the repository [**Recognizers-Text**](https://github.com/Microsoft/Recognizers-Text). Customizing them through LUIS could have adverse effects on the resolution of them, so any bugs encountered or fixes written should be mentioned in that repo.

Specifically for the recognizers, Spanish, English and Chinese open source right now. As an example, here's a link for the [datetime recognizers](https://github.com/Microsoft/Recognizers-Text/tree/master/Microsoft.Recognizers.Text.DateTime). There is currently work being done for French recognizers, and I know they are accepting contributions for the other languages as well.

Comment: This does not answer the question. We couldn't care less about Microsoft teams internally work. It is not unreasonable to expect that if in an utterance, there are 2 datetimes, they be identified separately.

Answer (score 1):

I'll often use composite entities for this scenario, so e.g. "{date of [$event] is [$datetimeV2]}, {date of [$event] is [$datetimeV2]}" hands me back two composites, where the $event entity will help me disambiguate.

Answer (score 1):

LUIS patterns would also help you to name the slots you want to fill with the two dates. Your response example even show "role" no being set. Patterns were designed for that.